# defining a mongodb collection architecture to define user ,roles and their permissions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, aggregation

Hi I am developing a MERN application in which there will be some users say manager, associate and super admin where each one will have a different userid, role and permission. Based on that i will be displaying the required pages of the app. I am planning to create a seperate collection for each of these like below

USER_COLLECTION

```
{
user_id:1,
user_mail:ss@mail.com,
role_id:11,
permissions:[c,r,u,d]
}
```

ROLE_COLLECTION

```
{
role_id:11,
user_id:1,
role_name:"super_admin"
}
```

PERMISSIONS_COLLECTION

```
{
permission_id:111,
user_id:[1],// there can be multiple users for this permission
role_id:[11],// there can be multiple roles for this permission
permission_name:"CREATE"
}
```

will this approach work? Or should i take another approach?

Comment: Refer this for some ideas: [MongoDB Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Comment: What do you mean by "this approach work"? Why don't you just try out your design to see whether it suits your need?

Comment: @ray : I am new to mongodb and i just wanted to know if this structure will be good or there is more to it.. I just wanted help to guide me if i am going in the right path.

Comment: It's ok :) What I mean is that this kind of question usually involves far alot of detail that more than a common SO question can holds, so it could be hard for the community here to answer. But for a quick look, you are maintaining 2-way pointer between different collections, which could involve huge effort when the collection grows. If you are looking for a common RBAC system, you may just want the user collection to have array holding the roles that the user has; and the role collection holding the permissions associated to each role os that you can do the lookup starting from user.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on the same thing and here is my appraoch,

EXPLANATION :

> Here first I create the user object/document in the mongodb collection, the I have a roles collection in which I record all the ids of all the roles, and then we have a permission schema.
> In the Above context, permission document will act as a permission policy document, we define the list of permissions first or we can say valid permissions that we can later assign to the roles, and in our server code we add a middleware in which we can first check if that user role have that particular permission to access this endpoint.

**NOTE :** It can be complex or confusing, let me know if you found it understandable or should I share some more snippets with you so you can get the concept better.

USER SCHEME :

```
import mongoose, { type Document, Schema } from "mongoose";
import status from "../enum/user.status.js";
import userHook from "../hooks/user.hook.js";

export interface UserDocument extends Document {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
  status: string;
  isAllowNewsletters: boolean;
  billingInfo: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  projects: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  bugReports: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  userDetail: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  date: Date;
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user",
    required: false,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: status.Inactive,
  },
  isAllowNewsletters: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: false,
  },
  billingInfo: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "BillingInfo",
  },
  projects: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Project",
  },
  bugReports: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "BugReport",
  },
  userDetail: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "UserDetail",
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

userSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    ret.userId = ret._id.toString();
    delete ret._id;
    delete ret.__v;
    delete ret.password;
  },
});

userHook(userSchema);
export default userSchema;
```

ROLES SCHEME :

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

export interface RolesDocument extends Document {
  admins: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId];
  users: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId];
  testers: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId];
  developers: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId];
  projectManagers: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId];
}

const roleSchema = new Schema<RolesDocument>(
  {
    admins: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: "User",
      required: false,
    },
    users: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: "User",
      required: false,
    },
    testers: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: "User",
      required: false,
    },
    developers: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: "User",
      required: false,
    },
    projectManagers: {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: "User",
      required: false,
    },
  },

  { timestamps: true },
);

export default roleSchema;
```

PERMISSION SCHEME :

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";

export interface PermissionDocument extends Document {
  permissions: [string];
  version: string;
  status: string;
  admin: {
    permissions: [string];
  };
  user: {
    permissions: [string];
  };
  tester: {
    permissions: [string];
  };
  developer: {
    permissions: [string];
  };
  projectManager: {
    permissions: [string];
  };
}

const permissionSchema = new Schema<PermissionDocument>(
  {
    permissions: {
      type: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    version: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "active",
    },
    admin: {
      permissions: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
      },
    },
    user: {
      permissions: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
      },
    },
    tester: {
      permissions: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
      },
    },
    developer: {
      permissions: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
      },
    },
    projectManager: {
      permissions: {
        type: [String],
        required: false,
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
permissionSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    ret.permissionId = ret._id.toString();
    delete ret._id;
    delete ret.__v;
  },
});

export default permissionSchema;
```